# How can I pull an item (which is an object) out of an array, which is a property of a document in a MongoDB collection using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

Say I have this document in my MongoDB collection:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  arr: [{
      nums: {
        a: 2,
      },
      ... (other properties)
    },
    {
      nums: {
        a: 3,
      },
      ... (other properties)
  }],
  ... (other properties)
}
```

How can I delete every object in the arr of this object where the property a in the nums object is equal to 2 **using Mongoose**. (The _id of the document is given)

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, ???)
```

But what is '???' ?

EDIT:
This is my configuration (what's in my collection "items"):

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"610f8fcc3688bd49e4664c2b"},
  "arr":[
    {"obj":{"a": 2,"b": 3}}
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I then run this code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");

const Item = new mongoose.model(
  "item",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    arr: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  })
);

mongoose
  .connect(config.get("mongoURI"), {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(async () => {
    console.log("Connected to Mongo...");
    await Item.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: "610f8fcc3688bd49e4664c2b" },
      { $pull: { arr: { "obj.a": 2 } } }
    );
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

This is my response (what's in my collection after I've executed the code above)

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"610f8fcc3688bd49e4664c2b"},
  "arr":[
    {"obj":{"a": 2,"b": 3}}
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

(nothing has changed)

Btw.: My console doesn't show any errors